# Matching 8-bit characters in Haskell Text.Regex.Posix.ByteString

Tags: regex, haskell, ascii, bytestring

my Haskell application reads input as a list of ByteString and I'm using Text.Regex.Posix.ByteString.regexec to find matches.  Some input has a character code 253 (it's a 1/2 symbol in one IBM PC character set) and it seems that the pattern '.' (i.e., dot, "match any character") doesn't match it.  Any way to make it match ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on a Windows Haskell install:

```
> length $ ((pack ['\1'..'\253']) =~ "." :: [[ByteString]])
252
```

I.e. dot matches all characters in range including code 253.

Note that the library calls out to the underlying posix regex matcher, typically, I assume, from `glibc`.

So I would imagine any issue you have would be with that precise underlying c implementation.

Something like `Text.Regex.TDFA.ByteString` might give you clearer behavior in this case, since it is all in Haskell?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense. Why would you want to match a half-character? `.` will match the full character.

Comment: It's only half a character in certain encodings such as UTF-8.  I'm looking to match 8-bit characters.